# Как сделать чтобы после генерации списка пользователь выдел список начиная с первого элемента?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Внутри канваса создал ScrollView,который содержит в себе Content. Content в свою очередь содержит динамический список.Чтобы все элементы показывались правильно и что размер Сontent'а менялся автоматически,добавил Vertical Layout Group && Content Size Fitter.Всё хорошо работает, но мне нужно чтобы после генерации списка  пользователь выдел список начиная с первого элемента,а ни со середины списка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы хотите вручную через код устанавливать насколько прокручен должен быть ваш ScrollView? Для этого есть 3 свойства: [verticalNormalizedPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-verticalNormalizedPosition.html), [horizontalNormalizedPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-horizontalNormalizedPosition.html), [normalizedPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-normalizedPosition.html).

Первые два - тип данных `float` от 0 до 1, второе - `Vector2`, состоящий из первых двух.

Например, таким образом можно установить прокрученность `ScrollRect` на половину по вертикали:

```
GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.5f;
```

Чтобы показывать пользователю список с самого начала, нужно установить `verticalNormalizedPosition` на `1`

Comment: Максим Спасибо вам большое.Очень помогли.)

Answer (score 1):

В пайплайне рендера UI элементы отображаются по порядку иерархии.

Что бы их отсортировать нужно либо для всех элементов установить `SetParent(null)`, после чего вернуть в отсортированном порядке:

```
Transform MainTransform = transform;
List<Transform> Childs = new List<Transform>();
for (int i = 0; i < MainTransform.childCount; i++)
    Childs.Add(MainTransform.GetChild(i));
foreach (Transform child in Childs)
    child.SetParent(null);
// sort
foreach (Transform child in Childs)
    child.SetParent(Transform);
```

Либо тупо удалить все элементы и создать их заново.

Comment: спасибо вам за ваш ответ.  Можете посмотреть еще раз на картинку, я изменил ее.В Content элементы уже добавляются  в отсортированном виде по алфавиту.Но каждый раз  при обновление Content показывается ровно со середины.